# How to select only recently updated records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

Have a table in postgres(called ledger) that keeps data about some keywords with a structure like below:

```
 - id
 - keyword
 - updatedAt
 - createdAt
 - ...other details
```

A single keyword may be in multiple rows, want a query such that it will return only the recent record to a keyword. In other words, will want to select all from ledger but with each keyword appearing once(only the very recent update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

You did not mention what is the initial value of the `updatedat` column. Assuming it is `null`:

```sql
select distinct on (keyword) 
    keyword, 
    coalesce(updatedat, createdat) as last_change_time, 
    other_column
from ledger
order by keyword, last_change_time desc
```